# Update multirecords in Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have created following piece of code in order to update multiple records using Laravel.

```
$all_id =[1,2,3,4,5];
$desc = ['one','two','three','four','five'];
Descriptions::whereIn('id', $all_id)->update(['description' => $a]);
```

The script above works only if I put a single value for `description`.

```
Descriptions::whereIn('id', $all_id)->update(['description' =>   'description]);
```

I need to pass the array `$des` in order to update all descriptions related to their `id`s.

Comment: Do you want to update each id with it's corresponding description?

Comment: Hi, yes, exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot run multiple row updates with different values at the same time. You can do something like this.

```
$ids = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
$desc = ['one','two','three','four','five'];

foreach ($ids as $key => $id) {
    Descriptions::where('id', $id)->update(['description' => $desc[$key]]);
}
```

You can use `whereIn` condition on id list if you need to update multiple rows with the same data.

If you really need to then you could use raw query to do this. Something like

```
UPDATE descriptions
SET description = (case when id = 1 then 'one'
                     when id = 2 then 'two'
                     when id = 3 then 'three'
                     when id = 4 then 'four'
                     when id = 5 then 'five'
                end)
WHERE id in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

Comment: Hi, using the foreach I get this error: Undefined offset: 26

Comment: @Robert updated the code. I forgot to use the key for fetching description value.